# Como puedo ahcer para que el modal se cierre al momento de llenar el formulario y guardar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap, mvc

Ayudenme con esto por favor, es algo urgente y no se como resolverlo.
**Este es el modal, y quiero que al momento de que el usuario llene dicho modal, este se cierre.
ya que cuando se llenar y se guarda, dicho modal se queda abierto mostrando la pagina principal en el espacio del modal,**

[image]

`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sube tu reporte</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="IFRAME" src="@Url.Action("Reporte","Home")" style="width:100%; 
height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé que estas usando para el desarrollo pero supongo que como la mayoría de tecnologías que son enfocadas en el frontend utilizan javascript o un derivado del mismo, así que puedes utilizar el .remove() de javascript luego de haber guardado la información del formulario

```
var element = document.getElementById("exampleModal");
     element.remove();
```

Comment: estoy usando mvc y asp.net

Comment: ah vale compañero, me puse a investigar y ví que se puede implementar javascript con asp.net, pero también ví que otra persona tenía el mismo problema que tienes y lo pudo resolver en asp.net, la solución es la misma, lo que cambia son cosas de estética del código, acá esta el link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802588/remove-an-asp-net-control-from-code-behind

Comment: espero ayudarte con eso

Comment: entonces la solucion es para el javascript?

Comment: mirate el link que coloqué, ahí esta escrito en asp.net

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, soy algo nuevo en estas cosas, y la solucion no se bien donde colocarla

Comment: la colocas después de haber consumido el servicio que guarda la información del formulario en la base de datos

Comment: en tu ejemplo el document hace referencia a que?

Comment: al Dom, lo que hace la línea document.getElementById("exampleModal"); es obtener el elemento que contenga ese id para que después lo podamos modificar, en tu caso es removerlo u ocultarlo

Comment: si pongo tu ejemplo asi como esta, me da error en el document, tengo que reemplazarlo por algo?

Comment: no te funciona porque es javascript puro, mirate el siguiente link que es lo mismo que dice acá pero en código asp.net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802588/remove-an-asp-net-control-from-code-behind

Comment: el "page" a que se refiere?

Comment: se reemplaza por el nombre del proyecto?

Comment: nop por lo que entiendo es un objeto del DOM

Comment: entiendo, y el DOM donde se encuentra?

Comment: amigo el DOM es una estructura de objetos que genera el navegador cuando corre nuestro aplicativo, es decir que cada elemento de la página termina siendo un objeto para el navegador, es solo eso